# Android - Realm - Instrumented Unit Tests

Tags: android, realm

everybody. I have a question bounded to Realm. Realm is new technology for me. I need test functionality - correctness of updates, inserts, links between objects, etc.  I have DAO pattern with Dagger and I can inject instance of RealmConfiguration. Is good choice to use Instrumented Unit Test with database in memory? Or is better mock all Realm objects. Thank you.

Comment: Well if you want to ensure Realm correctness, then an instrumentation test running "unit tests" over Realm is a good choice with in-memory. I'd give it a different `name` param too.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is there any good tutorial for testing realm and have some explanation ?

Comment: Apart from Realm's own instrumentation tests, I haven't seen any, anywhere.